# Hiding Output Direction Raster from Euclidean Distance in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Is there any way to hide (for aesthetic reasons) an empty Output Direction Raster resulting from an Euclidean Distance in ModelBuilder?

I currently have a ModelBuilder model for a project that contains quite a few Euclidean Distance tools, each with its distance raster and its direction raster. I don't need the latter for anything, actually i don't even chose to create it, so my model is full of white squares that give no output that end up bothering.

Comment: but you cannot just delete them for some reason? I'm confused.

Comment: No, deleting the Euclidean Direction Raster square deletes the whole tool, and I want to keep the Euclidean Distance tool square and the Euclidean Distance Raster square. I want to be able to delete the Direction one so the rest of the diagram can be "compressed" and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from display property. Select the `Output Direction Raster -> right-click -> Display properties`:

[image]

Delete the text beside the name  and change the Border Width to empty:

[image]

Select the Arrow and do the same thing by changing the color of the arrow and arrow head to white color:

[image]

Deselect the arrow. Here is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that, although this solution does not answer my question as it only colors them in white. The space they occupy still "exists". What I'd like to know is if there's a way to hide them completely, as I chose not to generate this output, and so the rest of the diagram rearranges as if they simply don't exist.

Comment: @adriasf As you said this is for aesthetic purpose, turning them white is a workaround solution. I know it is not exactly what you want, but I think this is the only solution available unless someone else has better idea.